# File in .gitignore is not getting ignored

Tags: git

As the title says, I put a filepath in my repo's .gitignore
file... But when that file changes (which happens automatically) I see it when I run `git status`

```
~/.dotfiles (master)✹ ᐅ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   home_stuff/.config/rofi/theme.rasi

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

And this is my input in the .gitignore file:
`home_stuff/.config/rofi/theme.rasi`

What's up with that?

Comment: gitignore doesnt work on files in the repo. I think it may have been tracked in the past. Try removing the files from cache (making it so no files are tracked) and then adding them back `git rm -r –cached .` then
`git add .` then 
`git commit`

Comment: @Narzard Yep, that was the issue indeed. That file was getting tracked and I wanted it out. Your solution worked. Make it an answer so I can accept it if you like.

Comment: @RegEdit Yes I'm sure. .gitignore is at the root of the repo. Narzard's comment solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes files that have previously been tracked need to be removed from the cache to get things to work properly. You should be able to solve this with these 3 commands.

`git rm -r -cached .`  (Removes cache and all files from being tracked.)

`git add .` (Adds your files back, sans the file that will be ignored)

`git commit`  (commits new files)

Answer (score 0):

Files already tracked by Git are not affected.

This is stated in the second line of the description. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use git rm --cached.